# Ubuntu環境のバックアップ方法

Tags: ubuntu

お世話になります。
現在VPSにUbuntu18.04をインストールして利用しています。
今回、この環境を別サーバーにまるごとコピーしたいと考えているのですが、何かよい方法はないでしょうか。
一応ざっと調べてみたところ、MondoRescueというのが見つかりましたが、Ubuntu18に対応していないようで、ほかの方法を探しています。
何かよい方法があれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

詳しい使い方については割愛しますが、有名どころとしては [CloneZilla](https://www.clonezilla.org/) 辺りではないでしょうか。
LiveCD から起動して、パーティション単位でのバックアップ/リストア等に対応しています。

ユーティリティの Partimage を使う事になると思うので、類似のディストリビューションとして 
 [SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) もあります。

上記の内容に加えて、その他様々な方法が関連サイトの [How to back up my entire system? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/7809) で紹介されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえず、ざっと調べてみましたが、よくわかりませんでした。もうちょっと調べてみます。